# Overwrite ansible variable from file fails

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to overwrite a previously defined variable `my_var` (when it's set to `LATEST`) by loading a value from a file (containing, say, `NEWVALUE`).

```
- name: Load from file
  vars:
    my_var: "{{ lookup('file', '~/file.txt') }}"
    my_var2: "{{ lookup('file', '~/file.txt') }}"
  debug: msg="my_var is {{ my_var }} my_var2 is {{ my_var2 }}"
  when: "{{ my_var=='LATEST' }}"
```

This prints

```
ok: [host] ==> {
    "msg": "my_var is LATEST my_var2 is NEWVALUE"
}
```

So I feel that I've verified that I'm loading the value correctly.. but for some reason I can't set the result of `lookup` in a previously set variable. Disabling the `when` clause doesn't seem to make any difference.

Should I be able to do this? As an alternative I'm going to use a third variable and just set it to either the preexisting value or the value from the file - but this seems like an unnecessary step to me.

Ansible version **2.1.0.0** b.t.w.

Comment: I should have been using `set_fact` but the same problem still existed because the fact was being provided as a command-line environment variable it can't be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

The vars you defined in your example only are available for the single debug task.

As you mentioned in the comment you figured this out and used set_fact instead. And yes, this won't work if you have passed the same variable as extra-var, as it has the [highest precedence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). There is no way to override a variable you passed as extra-var.